# How can I implement the photos swiping like iOS Photos app using the UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

Suppose I have a large array of photoIds which I can use in the Photos APP requestPhoto API to fetch a photo. How can I implement the `UIPageViewController` to accommodate a large array as such. Wouldn't creating a view controller for each of these photos on swiping left/right cause a degradation of performance of the App. Could anyone suggest a better approach to this? I've looked everywhere but couldn't find anything. I suppose another way to frame this question would be 'How can I implement the `UIPageViewController` with a dynamic set of data instead of a static number?

Comment: You can use `CollectionView` instead.

Comment: You can either build your custom solution using `CollectionView` or you can use a third party open source library such as `iCarousel` https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: You can take help from the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tl0ZbKR23LE Here Brain shows a demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else struggling with the same issue. I found this video very helpful. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ItdPXinQOp8?

According to this, I made an array with lazy var that pushes all the view controllers in the array. The view controller is only loaded when it is needed so that prevents any performance degradation. So it doesn't matter if you have n number of view controllers.

## So basically the approach will be:

1. Have an array with all the imageIDs you want to swipe through
2. Make a lazy var newArray which will iterate through the imageIDs(Array) and fetch the images with an api call. Dont worry it will only call the api when required. Initialize the Detailed View controller with the received image and push viewcontroller in newArray.
3. Set up UIPagecontroller delegates as usual using the newly formed array of all the viewcontrollers.

Comment: Looks like the video has now been marked as private

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following approach

1. Use UICollectionView for your photos interface.
2. Choose horizontal scrolling for the collectionview for so your users can swipe left and right.
3. The datasource array can hold the sources for your photos and that allows your photoviewer to be dynamic. Just update the array and trigger a reloadData() on the collectionview to refresh the UI. You can keep track of the item that the user was last viewing and scroll to that upon refresh, if you don't want to make the user aware of the refresh.
4. Collectionview will automatically handle memory for you, so you don't have to be concerned about that.

Comment: This is how I implemented the Thumbnails photos view. I was actually talking about the Detailed View where the user scrolls left/right between the detailed views on clicking the collection view thumbnails instead of having to go back to the thumbnail view all the time.

Comment: The detail view can have a collection view with each cell fitting the screen (or how ever large you want the enlarged view to be). Once the user is in the detail view for one image, he can swipe left or right to view other images.

Comment: Interesting! I did not know that. Thank you. Take my upvote